# How would you make sure a inputted value is a number?

Tags: python

I finished my program of craps!  now I seem to be able to break it very easily...

How would I check if a value is a int or float before I convert it from a string...  I tried using ValueError: but I think because the function is not part of a loop I cant...  Sorry first time I needed to think of this!

My code works great if the user actually follows directions(HA!) but will break if I enter something like "THREE" instead of 3.
Code:

```
def parse_message(msg):

    if len(msg) >= 1:
        msg = msg.split(' ')
        options = {'!resetme': command_reset_player,
                   '!removebets': command_remove_bets}
        if msg[0] == '!bet':
            if msg[1] == 'place':
                if int(msg[2]) in [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10] :
                    if float(msg[3]) > 1:
                        UpdateBets.PlaceBet(sender, int(msg[2]), float(msg[3]))
            if msg[1] == 'pass':
                if float(msg[2]) > 1:
                    UpdateBets.PassBet(sender, float(msg[2]))
            if msg[1] == 'passodds':
                if float(msg[2]) > 1:
                    UpdateBets.PassOdds(sender, float(msg[2]))
            if msg[1] == 'hard':
               if int(msg[2]) in [4, 6, 8, 10] :
                   if float(msg[3]) > 1:
                       UpdateBets.HardBet(sender, int(msg[2]), float(msg[3]))
```

Comment: Why don't you define a function as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    val = int(val)
except ValueError:
    print('Not an int')
```

Comment: hmm so before every if that needs to be an int or float I run the loop with the except statement....  seems like it might work.

Comment: Actually for the str->int conversion, you may be better off using `val.isdigit()` to test if the string is numeric - from a performance perspective, it likely depends on whether you expect to get mostly valid strings or not

Comment: `"-1".isdigit()` is considered false but `int("-1")` is completely valid, the way you have posted is the best, as is described in the various answers that this question is a dup of.